# Update Excel file via outlook with vba

Tags: vba, outlook, xlsx

I currently have this code in outlook:

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
saveFolder = "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\files"
For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
If InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, ".xlsx") Then
objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & dateFormat & objAtt.DisplayName
End If
Set objAtt = Nothing
Next
End Sub
```

Now I want that the file will be updated and only rows should be added to the file instead of overriding it.

These information could help:

- The file i get will be delivered with the same format/table/columns-only the data will change

  - The file will be with the same `name.xlsx`

Answer (score 0):

start with something like

```
Sub ExcelExport(path_to_your_file As String)
    Dim xlApp As Object, xlBook As Object

    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If xlApp Is Nothing Then
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.open path_to_your_file
```

then put your Excel-code into here, you could even record that code in Excel...

and as end:

```
    xlBook.Close
    Set xlBook = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

I hope this helps you,
Max

P.S. maybe this link is interesting http://www.office-loesung.de/ftopic153694_0_0_asc.php&start=30